# Extra constant in solution of ODE using DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

A paper that I have states that the solution of the ODE
$$-\frac{\left(\frac{\pi  k}{a}\right)^2 Y(y)}{G_y}+\frac{Y''(y)}{G_x}+\frac{8 \theta }{\pi  k}=0$$
is
$$Y=A\sinh\left(\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)+B\cosh\left(\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)+\frac{8 \theta }{(\pi  k)^3}a^2$$
where $\mu=\sqrt{\frac{G_x}{G_y}}$ and $a$, $G_y$, $G_x$, $\theta$ and $k$ are constants. When I enter this code in Mathematica

```
ode = Y''[y]/Gx - 1/Gy ((k π)/a)^2 Y[y] + 8/π θ/k == 0;
FullSimplify[DSolve[ode, Y[y], y]]
```

I get

> ```
> {{Y[y] -> 
>       (8 a^2 Gy θ)/(k^3 π^3) + 
>       E^((Sqrt[Gx] k π y)/(a Sqrt[Gy])) C[1] +
>       E^(-((Sqrt[Gx] k π y)/(a Sqrt[Gy]))) C[2]}}
> ```

or

$$Y=\frac{8 a^2 G_y \theta }{\pi ^3 k^3}+c_1 \exp\left(\frac{\pi  \sqrt{G_x} k y}{a \sqrt{G_y}}\right)+c_2 \exp\left(-\frac{\pi  \sqrt{G_x} k y}{a \sqrt{G_y}}\right)$$

Why is there an extra $G_y$ in the $\frac{8 a^2 G_y \theta }{\pi ^3 k^3}$ term?

Comment: Well, you may explain it yourself if you set $c_1$ and $c_2$ to $0$ and substitute it into the ODE. (That means that a authors of the paper made a mistake.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be about the paper and not about `Mathematica`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mathematica answer is correct. One way to find the particular solution is to use variation of parameters (another is undetermined coefficients).

$$
\frac{1}{Gx}Y^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)  -\frac{1}{G_{y}}\left(
\frac{\pi k}{a}\right)  ^{2}Y\left(  y\right)  =-\frac{8\theta}{\pi k}
$$

Putting it in normal form (for use with variation of paramaters)

$$
Y^{\prime\prime}\left(  y\right)  -\frac{Gx}{G_{y}}\left(  \frac{\pi k}
{a}\right)  ^{2}Y\left(  y\right)  =-\frac{8\theta}{\pi k}Gx
$$

Using Variation of parameters to find particular solution, let
$$
Y_{p}\left(  y\right)  =Y_{1}\left(  y\right)  u_{1}\left(  y\right)
+Y_{2}\left(  y\right)  u_{2}\left(  y\right)
$$

Where $Y_{1}\left(  y\right)  =\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)
,Y_{2}\left(  y\right)  =\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  $ then, using
$F=-\frac{8\theta}{\pi k}Gx$

\begin{align}
u_{1}\left(  y\right)    & =-\int\frac{Y_{2}F}{W}dy\tag{1}\\
u_{2}\left(  y\right)    & =\int\frac{Y_{1}F}{W}dy\tag{2}
\end{align}

Where $W$ is the Wronskian

\begin{align*}
W  & =
\begin{vmatrix}
Y_{1} & Y_{2}\\
Y_{1}^{\prime} & Y_{2}^{\prime}
\end{vmatrix}
=
\begin{vmatrix}
\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)   & \cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  \\
\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)   & \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)
\end{vmatrix}
\\
& =\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}\sinh^{2}\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  -\frac{k\pi
\mu}{a}\cosh^{2}\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  \\
& =\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}\left(  \sinh^{2}\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)
-\cosh^{2}\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  \right)  \\
& =-\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}
\end{align*}

Hence (1) becomes

\begin{align*}
u_{1}\left(  y\right)    & =-\int\frac{\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)
\frac{8\theta}{\pi k}Gx}{\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}}dy\\
& =-\frac{8a\theta G_{x}}{k^{2}\pi^{2}\mu}\int\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  dy\\
& =-\frac{8a\theta G_{x}}{k^{2}\pi^{2}\mu}\frac{\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  }{\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}}\\
& =-\frac{8a^{2}\theta G_{x}}{k^{3}\pi^{3}\mu^{2}}\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu
}{a}y\right)
\end{align*}

And (2) becomes

\begin{align*}
u_{2}\left(  y\right)    & =\int\frac{\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)
\frac{8\theta}{\pi k}G_{x}}{\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}}dy\\
& =\frac{8\theta aG_{x}}{k^{2}\pi^{2}\mu}\int\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  dy\\
& =\frac{8\theta aG_{x}}{k^{2}\pi^{2}\mu}\frac{\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  }{\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}}\\
& =\frac{8\theta a^{2}G_{x}}{k^{3}\pi^{3}\mu^{2}}\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu
}{a}y\right)
\end{align*}

Therefore the particular solution is

\begin{align*}
Y_{p}\left(  y\right)    & =\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  \left(
-\frac{8a^{2}\theta G_{x}}{k^{3}\pi^{3}\mu^{2}}\sinh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  \right)  +\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  \left(
\frac{8\theta a^{2}G_{x}}{k^{3}\pi^{3}\mu^{2}}\cosh\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}
{a}y\right)  \right)  \\
& =\frac{8a^{2}\theta G_{x}}{k^{3}\pi^{3}\mu^{2}}\left(  -\sinh^{2}\left(
\frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)  +\cosh^{2}\left(  \frac{k\pi\mu}{a}y\right)
\right)  \\
& =\frac{8a^{2}\theta G_{x}}{k^{3}\pi^{3}\mu^{2}}
\end{align*}

But $\mu=\sqrt{\frac{G_{x}}{G_{y}}}$ hence the above becomes

$$
Y_{p}\left(  y\right)  =\frac{8a^{2}\theta}{\left(  k\pi\right)  ^{3}}G_{y}
$$

Comment: Thanks again! I made a follow up question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/193234/dsolve-leads-to-an-equation-that-is-different-from-paper-solution) because it wouldn't fit in the comment box. Basically this answer leads me to get numbers that are different from the solution that I'm following.

Answer (score 2):

Another method to get a particular solution is to note that $Y = K$, $K$ a constant, is a solution to
$$A\,Y''(y) + B\,Y(y) + C=0\,,$$
if $A,B,C$ are constants.
Plugging $Y=K$ into the differential equation yields
$$Y_p(y) = -C/B\,.$$
For
$$-\frac{\left(\frac{\pi  k}{a}\right)^2 Y(y)}{G_y}+\frac{Y''(y)}{G_x}+\frac{8 \theta }{\pi  k}=0\,,$$
we have
$$Y_p(y) = - \left. \frac{8 \theta }{\pi  k} \right/\left( -\frac{\left(\frac{\pi  k}{a}\right)^2}{G_y} \right) = \frac{8 a^2 G_y \theta }{\pi ^3 k^3} \,.$$

Or in *Mathematica*,

```
Solve[ode /. Y -> (K &), K]
(*  {{K -> (8 a^2 Gy θ)/(k^3 π^3)}}  *)
```

(Note `K` is an internal symbol, which normally should be avoided.)